# AngularFire2 unsubscribe on logout, database permission errors on unclosed subscription

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, observable, angularfire2

I have this code here using AngularFire2 version that I use to grab some member from the database on one of my components.

I have an issue when I call this logout in the same component. I unsubscribe from the Subscriptions but I still get the error in the console saying `Exception was thrown by user callback. Error: permission_denied at /users/uid`. I know it's because I am no longer signed in and my database rules don't allow this read operation. I don't know why it's still trying to read data if I already unsubscribed.

```
    constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private db: AngularFireDatabase) {
        this.user = afAuth.authState;

        this.userSub = this.user.subscribe(auth => {
            if (auth) {
                this.member = db.object('/users/' + auth.uid);
                this.dbSub = this.member.subscribe();
            }
        });
    }

    logout() {
        this.dbSub.unsubscribe();
        this.userSub.unsubscribe();

        this.afAuth.auth.signOut()
            .then(() => this.router.navigateByUrl('/login'));
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps you are using the observable with the `async` pipe somewhere in a template? If you are, that'll be another subscription.

Comment: Shouldn't that unsubscribe automatically

Comment: Yes, when the component is destroyed, etc., but not just because you call your logout method. There's not enough information in your question for it to be answerable.

Comment: This is a header component that is visible on every page

Comment: I know this is old, but I have the exact same issue and have been unable to resolve. I unsubscribe and still get the error.

Answer (score 6):

You could perhaps try using an RxJS Subject along with the operator `takeUntil()` to help ensure the observable is cleaned up prior to the `signOut()`:

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/takeUntil';

export class Foo {
    private ngUnsubscribe: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();

    constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private db: AngularFireDatabase) {
        this.user = afAuth.authState;

        this.userSub = this.user.subscribe(auth => {
            if (auth) {
                this.member = db.object('/users/' + auth.uid);

                this.dbSub = this.member
                    .takeUntil(ngUnsubscribe)
                    .subscribe(results => console.log(results));
            }
        });
    }

    logout() {
        this.ngUnsubscribe.next();
        this.ngUnsubscribe.complete();

        this.userSub.unsubscribe();

        this.afAuth.auth.signOut()
            .then(() => this.router.navigateByUrl('/login'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it better to use a BehaviourSubject rather than Subject?

Comment: In this situation `Subject` should be sufficient as it is simply using it as a conditional indicator rather than a mechanism to pass values to observers. It's calling `next()` without any value(s) so the value isn't really important in this example. `BehaviorSubject` would be important if it needed to provide an initial value and maybe use that as an additional factor in determining when to `complete()` the subject and trigger `takeUntil()` to complete the `dbSub` observable.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a logout button on many pages just navigate to a different page and call logout from there. Then you don't have to litter your code with unsubscribes. When you navigate to a different angular page the components and their subscribes will be garbage collected.

Comment: see: https://itnext.io/angular-rxjs-detecting-memory-leaks-bdd312a070a0